# Proper way to open a file in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart

I'm looking a way to open a file in flutter. Specifically a PDF.
I found everywhere: [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) but it seems to be deprecated:

> The plugin `open_file` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since
> a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Also I have to run my app using: `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`.

And when I run it, I get an error:

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
>   There was a failure while executing work items
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
>   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
>   The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Other than that, I also tried [open_document](https://pub.dev/packages/open_document), I installed, created the create provider_paths.xml, added the AndroidManifest but I got another error.

Any suggestions?
Thanks <3

Comment: With open_document I get:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openDocument on channel open_document)

Comment: update, open_file is no longer deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I installed the [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package using `flutter pub add open_file`, it downloaded version 2.1.1, even though in the console it said version **3.2.1** is available. This is probably due to some dependency issues in my code. So, to get the latest version, I typed the latest version number in the pubspec.yaml file and saved and got it installed that way.

Since the version 3.0.0 the [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package has been updated to the **v2 Android Plugin APIs**.

Comment: Newer versions: https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus

Answer (score 8):

Installing this package resolves the issue. The open_file package is out of date

[open_file_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) which is a fork of `open_file` and it is relatively well maintained compared to other forks