# How to open a pdf using android_intent_plus in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, file, pdf, android-intent

I have a .pdf on the download android folder, and I want to open it with flutter.

I tried:

```dart
final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW',
  // android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW  action_view
  data: Uri.encodeFull("/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf"),
  // content:
  // file: 
  // type: "application/*",
  flags: [
    Flag.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION,
    Flag.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION,
    Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
  ],
);
intent.launch();
```

But I get the following error:

```
V/IntentSender( 8997): Sending intent Intent { act=android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf flg=0x10000041 (has extras) }
E/MethodChannel#dev.fluttercommunity.plus/android_intent( 8997): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dev.fluttercommunity.plus/android_intent( 8997): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf flg=0x10000041 (has extras) }
dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidintent.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:95)
E/flutter ( 8997): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf flg=0x10000041 (has extras) }, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.os.Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.pdf flg=0x10000041 (has extras) }
E/flutter ( 8997): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 8997): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 8997): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8997): #2      AndroidIntent.launch (package:android_intent_plus/android_intent.dart:150:5)
E/flutter ( 8997): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Do I need an extra permission? provider? anything else?
Any suggestions?
Thankss <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

```
OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.pdf");
```

Comment: I tried using open_file. I get multiple errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72663846/proper-way-to-open-a-file-in-flutter

Comment: that's probably because you're not using the latest version of `open_file` that's supports null safety make sure it's version `^3.2.1` in your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: My god you are right. I wrote that version and it worked. I'm so dumb.
Thanks!